# How to check if a string contains unescaped regex control characters?

Tags: c++, regex, std

I am writing code that uses the C++ standard library's Basic RegEx pattern matching. The pattern matching as used is currently a bottleneck, and I want to optimize the common case of a simple string (with no special RegEx characters). How can I check if a given string contains unescaped RegEx special characters? I am able to detect special characters, but I am unable to except them if they are escaped.

```
std::regex special_character("[\.\[\]\*\^\$]*");
bool is_simple_string(std::string pat){
   return (bool) std::regex_match(pat, special_character);
}
```

EDIT: I have a list of regular expressions and I want to check which regex's a given string matches. My list of regex's is long enough that this is a performance bottleneck in my program. Most of my regex's are simple strings (with no control characters). I am trying to convert this to an  `unordered_set` of simple strings and a smaller list of complex regular expressions. This way I can perform constant-time lookup for the simple strings and only need to bother with a few complex regular expressions.

Comment: Regular expressions can also contain a bunch of other things like `()`. What's the purpose of this code? If you're putting something in a regular expression you should escape it by default unless you specifically want it to contain regular expression control characters.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to accumplish. What are the characters allowed?

Comment: One way to do a reliable test here is to compare an arbitrary string vs. its properly escaped regular expression form, and if there's no difference then there's no special characters.

Comment: `"\."` is an invalid escaped sequence, it should be `"\\."` or `R"(\.)"`.

Comment: The answer for the code in the question is to not use a regular expression. `str.find_first_of(“.[]*^$”) == std::string::npos)` is simpler, more readable, and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [12/13 special characters for regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html):

`\ [ { ( ) ^ $ . * ? | +` / `]`

so any pattern including one of the above would not be usable (directly) as search string (even if escaped).

If your pattern only contains regular characters and escaped special char, you might transform that pattern in regular string (`foo\(\)` -> `foo()`).

More complicated would be to transform pattern matching only a few set in the set (`(hello|hi)` -> `hello` and `hi`).

So pattern `R"(^[^\\[{()^$.*?|+]*$)"` would match regular string.

Pattern `R"(^(?:\\[\\[{()^$.*?|+\]]|[^\\[{()^$.*?|+])*$)"` would match regular string + string with only escaped special characters, so you can transform every `\X` in `X` to have regular string.